# Media Player On Complete Clicks 2nd Button from Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of Songs  and in UI, there are three `Buttons` named as play ,pause and resume. Now on `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()`, i want to performclick() on second Button of list view so that it could  automatically play  next song.

```
mPlayerforplanet.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
              viewHolder.play_button.getTag(position);
                    viewHolder.play_button.performClick();
                }
            }
        });
```

This piece of code works well in android  emulator but not in mobile device. if i am playing the first song, after completion of first song it going to 4th song and next 7th. Please help!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user first clicks the list set an integer to that list item position.On completion increment the integer and get the song data from listview adapter and play that song.Change the status of your play button according to the integer in adapter class.

Comment: i do the same bro on button play click i get the position from tag in and put in another int variable with increment and in on complete i set checked true this integer!! but i want to perform click in on complete !!! but now i am using these  for (int index = 0; index < planetList.size(); index++) {
                        planetList.get(index).setChecked(false);
                        int indexs = selectedPosition;
                        if (indexs < planetList.size())
                            planetList.get(indexs).setChecked(false);

Comment: Btw thnku for comment bro!!! i thing its view problem because Tv app having bigger rows and mobile devices have smaller rows.

Comment: Maybe you are performclick on button in wrong position,   find the button with this method findViewById(R.id.button).findViewWithTag(position"); then perform click

Comment: Bro. your code works well thanx for that. But the problem is my player On complete listener after song complete it called 4 times again that's why the values incremented automatically.

Comment: ok thnx bro !!! i have done it... but i have to set same tags for two dfifferent objects.. because i have setTag(position) . but i have to  use this postion getTag on Button Click and inecrement this on complete MediaPlayer!!